# Function to create a mask on list for elements that are in another set?

Tags: python

I have lists like this:

```
a=["a","b","c"]
b=["a","c","d","e"]
```

and I want to create a mask on `b` on elements that are in `a`. Hence, I am looking for this output:

```
[True,True,False,False]
```

because elements `"a"` and `"c"` are in set `a`. How would this be done without the use of `for`-loops?

Comment: It is impossible without the use of for loops (and I include list comprehensions in that).  Why would you want to?  What's the point?

Comment: Why the arbitrary restriction not to use for-loops? What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: Not impossible @TimRoberts just silly.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question because of the arbitrary restriction on `for`-loops. Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sets and `issuperset`:

```
A = set(a)
list(map(A.issuperset, b))
```

output:

```
[True, True, False, False]
```

as @juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out, [searching an element in a set is done in linear time](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

edit: variant to work with non iterables (or strings longer than one character):

```
A = set(a)
list(map(lambda x: A.issuperset([x]), b))
## OR
list(map(lambda x: x in A, b))
```

Comment: You should point out that `set` objects allow you to do this in linear time as opposed to quadratic.

Comment: good point @juanpa.arrivillaga I added it to the answer, thanks!

Comment: Tested on python 3.8.10

Comment: Do you have any error? What is the output?

Comment: @DanielHao it's also working on python 2.7, as I expected, so I'm not sure what is going on, try it in a fresh shell?

Comment: Explained earlier. ^^^ it's working fine. Thanks. Would be great to elaborate on the new edits, enable other types check ✅

Comment: @DanielHao Just saw it, I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion to avoid a for loop:

```
def mask(a,b):
    return [] if not b else [b[0] in a] + mask(a,b[1:])

(mask(["a","b","c"],["a","c","d","e"])
[True, True, False, False]
```

otherwise you can use the map function:

```
a=["a","b","c"]
b=["a","c","d","e"]

list(map(lambda x:x in a,b))
[True, True, False, False]
```

*Note that converting `a` to a set would make this faster but, since you are constrained to avoid a loop, i'm guessing that performance is not a pressing concern*

you could also use numpy which (in theory) could process things in parallel without an explicit loop:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array(["a","b","c"])
b=np.array(["a","c","d","e"])

np.isin(b,a)
array([ True,  True, False, False])
```

Comment: This really looks like a loop in disguise :p

Comment: Anything you do will be a loop in disguise.  Just more or less hidden.

Comment: That's what I was about to add ^^